# Sublime Text 3: Simple plug-in that changes color theme depending on remote host

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

**Setup:** I use Sublime Text 3 (ST), and I often have 2-3 different sessions with Sublime + iTerm2 open in different remote workspaces using [RemoteSubl](https://github.com/randy3k/RemoteSubl).

Using a simple batch script, I have set my iTerm2 to change colours (by activating a different iTerm user) when I ssh into a different host.

I was wondering if the same could be done for RemoteSubl? Such that when I open something from a specific host/ip/port, then Sublime opens in a different colour scheme, depending on the host/ip/port.

---

**Solution attempt:** So far, this is my attempt at building a small plugin that changes colour scheme when host is `remote_host`.

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class ExampleCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

    def run(self, view):

        try:

            host = view.settings().get('remote_subl.host')

            print(host)

            if host == 'remote_host':

                view.settings().set(
                    'color_scheme',
                    'Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Mariana.tmTheme')

                print(view.settings().get('color_scheme'))

        except:
            print("Not on remote_host")
            pass
```

---

**Problem**: When using using `view.settings().get('remote_subl.host')` in the console it works fine, and returns `remote_host`. However, when running the script `view.run_command('example')` I get the "Not on remote_host" print, indicating that the try loop fails for some reason.

---

**After Keiths suggestions**:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class ExampleCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

    def run(self, view):
        view = self.view
        host = view.settings().get('remote_subl.host', None)

        print(host)

        if host:

            view.settings().set(
                'color_scheme',
                'Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Mariana.tmTheme')

            print(view.settings().get('color_scheme'))

        if host is None:

            view.settings().set(
                'color_scheme',
                'Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme')

            print(view.settings().get('color_scheme'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`view` isn't an argument that is passed to the `TextCommand`'s `run` method. Instead, it is a property on `self`. Changing it to the following should work:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class ExampleCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

    def run(self, edit):
        view = self.view

        try:

            host = view.settings().get('remote_subl.host')

            print(host)

            if host == 'dsintmain':

                view.settings().set(
                    'color_scheme',
                    'Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Mariana.tmTheme')

                print(view.settings().get('color_scheme'))

        except:
            print("Not on remote_host")
            pass
```

I would also recommend printing the exception that occurs to help debug things like this in future. Even better, rather than expecting an exception in normal usage, provide a default value to the `get` method on the `settings` (i.e. `None`) and remove the exception handling altogether.

```
host = view.settings().get('remote_subl.host', None)
```

That way, if something does really go wrong, you'll see the traceback in the ST console.

Comment: Great. Can you point me to documentation of how I would go about running my small plug-in automatically when opening a remote workspace?

Comment: You would use something like `on_load_async` in an [EventListener](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.EventListener) class to detect when a file is loaded and check to see if the setting is set. An example of that is [this gist](https://gist.github.com/OdatNurd/2dd05cd2669d1b2bd4a14fc922170300) based on your original plugin.